# ReferenceError: document is not defined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom, referenceerror

when i try to run this it gives me This runtime  Error

```
    let Ele = document.getElementsByClassName("test") as HTMLSpanElement
    console.log(Ele.innerHTML)
```

## the Error ==>

## "Conversion of type 'HTMLCollectionOf' to type 'HTMLSpanElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first"

but after converting it I tried to run it on node And gives me
"ReferenceError: window is not defined"

and on the browser logs undefined

```
let Ele = document.getElementsByClassName("test")as unknown as HTMLSpanElement
    console.log(Ele.innerHTML)
```

## I tried to Edit my ts config settings

```
"target": "ES6"
   "lib": [
            "ES6",
            "DOM",
            "DOM.Iterable",
            "ESNext"
        ]
"module": "commonjs"
```

## node v18.13.0.

Comment: You're using node.js? The "window" and "document" variables are only available in the browser. Node applications don't have a window or DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains what the problem is: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a **collection** (array) of HTML elements, and you are trying to convert this collection into a **single** Element (of type `HTMLSpanElement`) which is a mistake.

You need to get the first item from the collection and convert it into a `HTMLSpanElement` object:

```
const ele = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];
if (ele instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
    console.log(Ele.innerHTML)
}
```